# 「CentOSサーバ」よりファイルをダウンロードする際、出来るだけ転送時間を短縮したい

Tags: network

**現状**
・FileZilla使用
・FTPダウンロード
・ファイル数が多い(5万件以上)と、処理完了まで時間がかかる

**知りたいこと**
・高速ダウンロードする方法
・FTPではなくSSHで接続すると、ダウンロード速度は早くなる？
・あるいは、複数ディレクトリを圧縮してダウンロードすると速度は速くなる？
・コマンドは？
・下記で、対象ディレクトリ内の全ファイルを再帰的に圧縮できるのでしょうか？

```
$ zip archive -r 対象ディレクトリ
```

Comment: FileZillaなどのGUIのFTPクライアントを使っているなら1サイトあたり1回の操作で十分な気がしますが、「2～3件ずつ選択してダウンロード」している理由はなんでしょうか。サーバ側で何かの制限があるのでしょうか。またはダウンロードする対象に何らかの条件があり全ファイルをダウンロードするのではまずいと言うことでしょうか。また、50サイトから2000ファイルずつダウンロードするというのはあまり一般的な利用方法とは言えませんが、差し支えない範囲で対象サイトや目的など具体的な情報を開示されるとよりよい回答が得られやすいと思います。(追加情報はコメントでは無く質問を編集して追記してください)

Comment: 転送速度を上げるのは目的ではなくて、転送時間を短縮したいのだと読み取りましたが私の認識は合ってますか？

Comment: 合っています。こちらの意向を汲み取っていただきありがとうございました。紛らわしいようなのでタイトルを再度変更しました

Answer (score 4, accepted):

速度とか高速という単語に引っかかるのですが、時間短縮したいという意図だと思いましたので 分かる範囲で回答します。

SSH (SCP) は暗号化するので遅くなります。

FTPは十分に速い部類の通信プロトコルですが、GUIの FTPクライアントが 5万件超のファイル一覧を取得すると その結果を受信するのに時間がかかってしまうことも考えられます。
できれば コマンドの ftp を覚えて 最短のオペレーションで ファイルを `get` するのがいいと思います。

もしも、ほんの少しでも早くしたいなら `nc` を使います。

> ・あるいは、複数ディレクトリを圧縮してダウンロードすると速度は速くなる？

オーバーヘッドとデータ量が減るので時間短縮が期待できます。
ただ転送速度は変わらないです。

> ・コマンドは？

Unix系でよく使うのは tar + gzip だと思います。
次のコマンドでアーカイブと圧縮を行い、 出来上がった `/var/tmp/hoge.tgz` をFTPで転送してください。

送信元サーバー

```
$ cd /path/to/コピー元/
$ tar cfz /var/tmp/hoge.tgz .
```

コピー先

```
$ ftp 送信元サーバーのIP
USER xxxxx
PASSWORD xxxxx
ftp> cd /path/to/対象ディレクトリ/
ftp> binary               (バイナリモード)
ftp> get hoge.tgz         (hoge.tgz をダウンロード)
ftp> bye                  (切断)
```

わずかでも速くしたければ `nc` を次のように使ってみてください。

コピー先 (tcp/12345 を待ち受けて、受け取ったデータを tar に渡して展開)

```
$ cd /path/to/展開先/
$ nc -l 12345 | tar xfvz -
```

送信元 (tar でアーカイブと圧縮を行い、データを nc に渡して コピー先の tcp/12345 ポート宛に転送)

```
$ tar cfz - /path/to/コピー元/ | nc -w 1 コピー先のIP 12345
```

> ・下記で、対象ディレクトリ内の全ファイルを再帰的に圧縮できるのでしょうか？
>
> $ zip archive -r 対象ディレクトリ

その認識で合ってます。

Answer (score 0):

サイトとのことですのでVPSはLinuxでしょうか？
でしたらSSHでログインすることは可能ですね？

SSHはどんなものか分からない場合は検索等をするか再度質問してください。

こういう場合はSSHなどを使って複数のファイルを一ファイルに圧縮。
そのファイルをダウンロードすると接続が途中で切れたりすることもなく簡単です。

Comment: 速度だけで比較した場合、SSHはFTPより速いのでしょうか？ それとも一ファイルに圧縮できるので、結果的に速くなるということでしょうか？